# How do I sort a file after a certain row in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, suse

I am trying to sort a file and store the output into a `tmp` file. This is what my file looks like:

this_is_my_file (with no extension)

```
Names   Last_Name_Initial
---
Alex   G
Nick   D
Jon   J
Cain   V
Anderson   S
Chris   W
```

I know the command to sort the file is `sort -n $PWD/this_is_my_file -o tmp` but how to I start the sort after the `---`? And a follow up question, how can you distinguish between a text or xml file if the file you are comparing has no extension?

Comment: You can sort by second column since it dont have `---`

Comment: @Rahul I want to sort the first column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
head -n 2 file && tail -n +3 file | sort
Names   Last_Name_Initial
---
Alex   G
Anderson   S
Cain   V
Chris   W
Jon   J
Nick   D
```

It does the job as follows:

1. Uses `head -n 2` to get first 2 header lines
2. Used `tail -n +3` to get all lines starting from 3rd line
3. Pipes `tail`'s output with `sort`
4. Merges head's output with `tail+sort` using `&&`

To **redirect output** you can use grouping in shell `{...}`

```
{ head -n 2 file && tail -n +3 file | sort; } > output
```

Comment: Explanation added in answer.

Comment: how do you redirect the output into another file?  `head -n 2 file && tail -n +3 file | sort > tmp`?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a grouping construct:

```
{
    # read and print the first 2 lines
    read line; echo "$line"
    read line; echo "$line"
    # and sort the rest
    sort
} < this_is_my_file
```

Also, awk:

```
awk 'NR <= 2 {print; next} {print | "sort"}' this_is_my_file
```

a follow up answer: in general, on a unix-y system, the name file makes no guarantees about the contents of a file. However, you could see what the [`file`](http://man.cx/file) command says about a file:

```
$ cat > contains_xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<foo>
<bar>baz</bar>
</foo>
$ file contains_xml
contains_xml: XML document text
$ cat > not_really.xml
this is plain text
$ file not_really.xml
not_really.xml: ASCII text
```